# How to deduce/print the currency code from the currency symbol using Python?

Tags: python, currency

I have certain documents from which i have extracted the currency symbol like €, £, $ etc.

I want to write a code in python where after reading these symbols it can give me the respective currency code as an output.

For eg. if i get the currency symbol as **€**, the output should be **EURO** or if the currency symbol is **$** the output should be **USD**

Comment: You can use a dictionary in Python to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). These are like Hash Tables.

```
currency = { "€": "EURO", "$": "USD" }
print (currency["$"])
```

Prints `USD`

Comment: Thanks a Arkajyoti... Worked like a charm for me.. on a different note though is there any package in python we can use to achieve the output and make the code more generic?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra What do you exactly mean by output here? Are you talking about traversing the dictionary, you don't need a separate package for that; a `for` loop would suffice: `for key in currency: # print (currency[key])`. About generality, I'm assuming you're talking about type-generics: you can use anything as key and value without mentioning the type, as long as all the keys have the same type (so should apply for the value types, independently). You can take a look at the link to the Python Docs that I've left in my answer.